# USB protection from short circuits

Tags: usb

I just bought the Hantek6022BE oscilloscope and realized (unfortunately too late) that it needs to connect two USBs to the computer to work.
I think it is because of a power issue (maybe 500 mA from a single port is not enough to supply the oscilloscope).

I unfortunately only have two USB ports on my laptop, so I need to buy a USB hub with multiple inputs so as to:

- Connect the first USB wire from the oscilloscope to the first port (USB1) on my PC.
- Connect the USB hub to the second port (USB2) on my PC:
- Connect the second USB wire of the oscilloscope to the USB hub.
- Connect the microcontroller to the USB hub.

*Isn't there a risk that for whatever reason it will draw too much current from the USB and create problems (overcurrents and/or short circuits)?*

I had a terrible experience (that I don't want to happen again) where my PC shut down without rebooting due to a short circuit during the Arduino - breadboard - USB connection... the battery had disconnected due to a safety issue, etc. What a nightmare!

*I am asking if my concerns are correct and therefore whether I should buy a USB hub that has protection so that the USB port is not damaged.*

And most importantly... are there USB hubs that have protection? Because usually online there are individual USB ports with protection... not USB hubs!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use a powered hub.

Comment: Such USB hubs don't exist that will connect to PC with two ports. Also the scope has nothing you can short and draw excess current like your Arduino and nearby metal objects. You have an XY problem. Powered USB hubs exist, and USB isolators.

Comment: Use a USB charger to power the scope, and if your PC don't recognize the scope just switch the cables.

Comment: I skimmed through the manual and nowhere it says you need two USB ports to PC. Can you explain or point to a manual that says two USB connections are required? Does it even have two USB ports?

Comment: @MiNiMe If the poor device really needs two sets of USB cables for more power; they should not come from different sources if they are like early external HDDs and CD burners that came with Y cables for getting power from two PC ports. You are sure to fry your PC or scope unless this is explicitly allowed configuration in a manual.

Comment: @Justme I don't know why KaleM *that it needs to connect two USBs to the computer to work* The only I can think of are exactly those Y-cables you mention.

Comment: He is asking for a way to take a device with one USB type B port (his oscilloscope) and split it into two USB type A connectors using a hub.  You definitely cannot do that.

Comment: @user1850479 Sure you can, but it would be.. something. But it would be funny to hear how the USB enumeration worked out.

Comment: @MiNiMe If it is an Y cable, it will definitely work with hub just like with a PC - one port has comms and power, the other port just used for extra power without enumeration. But it is clear that the oscilloscope is not an USB compliant device if it only has USB power input and requires more than 500mA from single USB2 port. USB3 ports can output 900mA.

Comment: I agree with @MiNiMe - there doesn't seem to be a need for two USB ports. Why do you think it does?

Comment: I also think that it's either USB compliant and uses only one USB input or it's not and shouldn't be powered with USB. Perhaps it needs a separate power supply but normally this power supply shouldn't be a second USB port.  That sounds very weird to me,

Comment: I still don't understand whether I should use two or one usb cable during normal operation of the oscilloscope. I'm sure during installation you need two ... but only during installation maybe. I have updated the main post by adding an image and what is in the manual, we may be able to glean some more information.

Comment: I have a better idea: I'll try connecting only the black usb and see if it works, then try only the red one.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting poor answers due to not being precise what you have and misusing the terminology.

Thanks to dandavis for digging up a photo, your USB oscilloscope comes with an Y cable, with one Type-B plug for scope end, and two Type-A plugs for data and extra power.

So your oscilloscope has only one Type-B port or receptacle, and your laptop has only two Type-A ports or receptacles.

Now, having seen this and possible other suggestions that may be dangerous, the only option to protect the laptop is to get a powered USB hub, preferably one that does not even work at all without external power supply. Some "USB docks" are like this. Just connect one USB port of laptop to hub, and all remaining cables to the powered hub. Shorting the Arduino may damage the hub or the hub might just give enough power to destroy the Arduino, but likely the PC is safe. Unless you manage to put say 12V on the USB 5V or data lines, which will destroy the USB hub IC and the 12V can propagate to the laptop.

Another option is to buy or otherwise acquire another old junk computer which is expendable, as you have seen, it makes no sense to use your expensive main laptop or PC for lab experiments that can instantly destroy it with a simple short circuit - for example if you short the USB 5V to one of USB data wires, the port may damage and be permanently unusable, or it might take the whole chipset down with it.

Now, for the oscilloscope Y cable, these cables are not USB compliant and they should not exist, no device should be made to require existence of these cables. The two plugs must always be connected to the same device, i.e. same PC, or same hub, as it is possible the 5V supply wires are just shorted together.

Therefore the suggestion to put one (black data) plug to laptop and the other (red power) plug to a power supply will short circuit the power supplies together and may damage the PC immediately. That's why they should not exist because they allow consumers to do dangerous connections that are not supposed to be possible with standard cables. In this case there is Type-B USB plug on one end so the 5V supplies are likely just short circuited together. Other, custom cables, may have some other connector on the device end, so they may be made to handle a PC and a separate power supply properly, but this is not possible with Type-B plug.

If your laptop has an USB3 or some sort of high current battery charging connector, it is allowed to give out more current than 500mA so it is possible that a single USB plug from scope is enough.

The laptops usually have protection and it survived by turning off power instead of melting or blowing up a fuse. Accidents happen but they also can be avoided by keeping your work area clean and thinking twice before making accidental connections.

Comment: I still don't understand whether I should use two or one usb cable during normal operation of the oscilloscope. I'm sure during installation you need two ... but only during installation maybe. I have updated the main post by adding an image and what is in the manual.

Comment: @KaleM Sorry but that's really a question to the scope manufacturer how to use their scope, especially since the manual is not updated on this part. We also don't know what kind of USB ports your laptop has, USB2, USB3, and can they provide more than bare minimum required by specs and how much it provides and how much the scope wants. Personally, I would just plug both in if it does not work with one. And they must be plugged into same exact device which have identical USB features - you don't want to fry your laptop by e.g. connecting one of the plugs to always on charging port.

Answer (score 1):

This is as logic an answer I can give:

Here's a screenshot from the [manufacturers productpage](http://www.hantek.com/products/detail/31) for your scope.
[image]

What type of computer is the scope connected to? How many USB cables can you count to? And finally from the very same page "USB2.0 interface, **no external power source required**, easy to use."

Comment: That pic doesn't show the end of the cable in question... You can see his bespoke dual-head USB cable (one red, one black) in https://4.allegroimg.com/original/01cb14/9145d611415887a63e6895a2e864/__-OSCYLOSKOP-CYFROWY-2-x-20MHZ-_-HANTEK6022BE-USB,

Answer (score 0):

A USB hub will not double the amount of current available. It's not able to yield more current than it takes from the USB laptop outlet.
If there is a short circuit, there is either a malfunction inside the oscilloscope or the cable is damaged.

Comment: A powered hub, as suggested by many already, will provide more current out than it takes from the laptop.

Comment: Justme How a hub can provide more current? Or are you talking about an externally powered hub?

Comment: Yes, a powered hub means they are externally powered with a power supply.

Comment: OK. I was thinking about a USB "splitter".... ;)

Comment: You can't just "split" USB, it's still a hub but unpowered externally, taking power for the hub too from the laptop.